# Prevent update notifications in OS X 10.10.2

Tags: macos, upgrade, software-update, notifications, preferences

I need to stay with OS X 10.10.2 because some legacy programs don't perform smoothly with later versions. Is there a way to completely prevent any OS X upgrade notifications from showing up?

Answer (score 1):

To configure updates in OS X Yosemite:

Go to **System Preferences** > **App Store**

From there you can uncheck the settings for reminders on updates.

While you are at it, you may find other settings in the **System Preferences** that are worth checking out.

[image: System Preferences App Store]